# Varying size container gets over-taken by footer

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a checkout system I am designing and I cannot get the footer to not eat the bottom div I have setup, unless I continually adjust the margin-bottom figure.

I have three divs nested into one. These nested divs show/hide as I proceed to the next one. The only one I will ever have an issue with is the last one because it will never be static. I use it to show a customers order, so if they have 10 different products then 10 images, name, price, etc show.

Every other area of my site that gets new things added to it, the footer responds and continuously goes down.

My fiddle isn't the best and my issue is really hard to generate as it isn't a static issue. Two products could be added and it would be fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/pfar54/rc5yffy7/

```
    .footerOut {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #202020;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    clear: both;
}
.footer {
    height: 420px;
    width: 960px;
}
/*----------Main div for Checkout Process--------*/
.checkoutprocess {
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    display: relative;
}
```

I have set everything to relative...added padding: bottom (took it out because it didn't do anything). Everything I try doesn't help.

The height of the container and border are irrelevant as I am just using those to test.

Anyone see why?

Comment: No, my footer is over lapping the content.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Your problem is footer is overlapped with content, And I found some Html Dom Structure issues ans css property Mistakes, I have cleaned up your code please verify this link below in comment